# Wordpresss Twenty Twenty-One how to make clickable articles?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

**Hi !**

I'm using Wordpres's **Twenty Twenty-One Theme** which I modified.
The fact is that I want articles to be fully clickable, not just the title and the "See the rest..." button.

I know I have to edit content-single.php because I defined my homepage to be the latest articles :

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <header class="entry-header alignwide">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php twenty_twenty_one_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages(
            array(
                'before'   => '<nav class="page-links" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Page', 'twentytwentyone' ) . '">',
                'after'    => '</nav>',
                /* translators: %: Page number. */
                'pagelink' => esc_html__( 'Page %', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer default-max-width">
        <?php twenty_twenty_one_entry_meta_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

    <?php if ( ! is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/author-bio' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </article>
</a>
```

But the `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">` does not work...

How can I do that ? I'n not used to PHP anymore ^^'

**Thank you in advance !**

EDIT :

So the function was applying to the post itself, but I want it to be applied to the posts in the hompeage post list.

So I did this :

```
function clickable_article( $content ) {
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    ?>        
        <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        // add a cursor 
            $( '.post' ).css("cursor", "pointer");
        // on content click go to article url
            $( '.post' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
                var url = window.location.href; 
                window.location = url;
            } );
        } );
        </script>
    <?php
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'clickable_article' );
```

Now the articles are clickables, but it just fully crashes my web navigator... It seems to be the `window.location = url;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work !

So to make the whole articles clickable in your Wordpress home page you need to :

1. Set the homepage to display the last articles
2. Ensure you have the "read more" link
3. Paste this code in your function.php :

```
function clickable_article( $content ) {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        ?>        
            <script>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                $( '.post' ).unbind().click(function() {
                    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
                    console.log(url);
                    window.location = url;
                } );
            })
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'clickable_article' );
```

You need to `.unbind()` the event, because the posts have several links (image, title, read more...) so the window.location does not get flooded with several urls and crashes your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this, in your child-theme functions.php:

```
function clickable_article( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        
        ?>
                      
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
// add a cursor 
    $( '.entry-content' ).css("cursor", "pointer");
// on content click go to article url
    $( '.entry-content' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        var url = window.location.href; 
        window.location = url;
    } );
} );
</script>
    
    <?php
    
    }
    
    return $content;
    
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'clickable_article' );
```

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 647 of wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-Le_Bon_Son/functions.php. Please fix it and try saving again. syntax error, unexpected token "<".
 - 
So the $content does have an issue :/

Comment: I've changed my code, look like jquery is a better solution. The code is tested and working. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! -  
No errors this time but it's not working, see the website here : https://mathis-backert.com/le-bon-son/ - 
Also, I removed the <a> tag from content-single.php. Should I have left it?

Comment: Can't find the code on your page. Did you paste it in your functions.php?

Comment: Yes I did, should I have pasted it somewhere else ?

Comment: Look like the code is not executing. Can't find it in page source.

Comment: See this new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063631/wordpress-theme-editor-code-not-exectuing-at-all)

Comment: Ok so the code IS executed, but the whole article is clickable in the article page. Not the article list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function clickable_article( $content ) {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        ?>
            <script>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            // add a cursor 
            $("article").each(function() {
          var copyUrl = $(this).find(".entry-title").attr("href");
          
          $(this).click(function() {
            window.location = copyUrl;
          });
        });
      });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    return $content;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'clickable_article' );
```

Comment: if it still does not work try checking classes I've used in my code.
Basically I get post title url for each article.

Comment: Thank you for your help man, you put me in the right path. Maybe I was not clear with what I wanted ;) See my answer :)

Comment: Well done, happy to help.